# Resultado de una consulta NULL

Tags: mysqli, null

Disculpen he estado intentando hacer umeo siguiente select:

```
$sql =mysqli_query ($mysqli, "SELECT hour_out FROM registro_lista WHERE num_c="316115377");
```

Yo se por phpMyAdmin que el campo que estoy consultando es NULL

Pero quiero ultizarlo en un If de la siguiente forma:

```
If (is_null($sql)) {

}
Else{

}
```

Pero se va directamente al else, cuando la consulta debe dar Null, estoy haciendo algo mal??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo que ayuda mucho es el apartado **Valores devueltos**  del Manual de PHP, para que sepamos cómo evaluar los resultados de las funciones.

En el caso de **`mysqli_query`**,  que es la función que estás usando, [el Manual dice lo siguiente en ese apartado](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php):

> Retorna `FALSE` en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo `SELECT`,
>   `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` o `EXPLAIN` es exitosa, `mysqli_query()` retornará
>   un objeto **`mysqli_result`**. Para otras consultas exitosas 
>   `mysqli_query()` retornará `TRUE`.

O sea que cuando usas `mysqli_query` tienes tres posibilidades de resultado:

- `FALSE`,
- un objeto `mysqli_result` o,
- `TRUE`.

Eso significa que aquí:

```
$sql =mysqli_query ($mysqli, "SELECT hour_out FROM registro_lista WHERE num_c="316115377");
```

el calor de `$sql` nunca será `NULL` ni siquiera en el caso de que la consulta falle y la variable `$sql` adquiera el valor `FALSE`, pues `FALSE` no es igual a `NULL`.

Si como dices, lo que quieres evaluar es el valor de la columna `hour_out` que te trae la consulta, entonces debes recuperar ese valor leyendo el objeto que te devuelve `mysqli_query` en caso de éxito.

Hay varios métodos para leer los objetos **`mysqli_result`**, uno de los más usados es **[`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)** el cual te devuelve el valor en un array asociativo en el que cada clave es el nombre de cada columna del `SELECT`:

```
$sql =mysqli_query ($mysqli, "SELECT hour_out FROM registro_lista WHERE num_c='316115377'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$hour = $row["hour_out"];
```

Y luego puedes comparar mediante:

```
if (is_null($hour)) {

}
else{

}
```

O simplemente mediante:

```
if ($hour) {

}
else{

}
```

O mediante un operador ternario:

```
$resultado = ($hour)  ?  "No es nulo"  :  "Es nulo";
echo $resultado;
```

> **NOTA:**
>
> Atención a tu consulta. Tenía un error de sintaxis. La he puesto así:
>   `"SELECT hour_out FROM registro_lista WHERE num_c='316115377'"`  pero
>   si la columna `num_c` es de un tipo numérico, es mejor que quites las
>   comillas simples que rodean al valor, poniéndolo así: `"SELECT
>   hour_out FROM registro_lista WHERE num_c=316115377"`

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de mucha ayuda ‍♂️

Comment: @RaúlArcos Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Te comento lo siguiente:

Para poder validar si el retorno de tu consulta es efectivamente NULL lo debes hacer si con la función `is_null()`, pero la variable debes indicar el nombre entre comillas de la columna que deseas validar si es o no NULL

Te dejo este ejemplo, que hice con PDO pero solo es cuestión lo adaptes a tus necesidades

```
<?php

$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ls;port=3307', 'root', '*****');

$consulta = $conexion->prepare("select * from m");
$consulta->execute();
$resultado = $consulta->fetch();

if(is_null($resultado["name"])){
    echo "No tiene valor";
}else{
    echo "Tiene valor";
```

> Como puedes observar mi `if()` es similar al tuyo solo que indico
>   entre corchetes la columna sobre la cual se va a estar trabajando que
>   para mi ejemplo es `"name"` tu solo escribe solo la columna que estes
>   trabajando

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Te comento que le hago algunas observaciones a tu código y pudiera quedar de la siguiente manera

```
$sql =mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT hour_out FROM registro_lista WHERE num_c = 316115377");
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($sql);

if(is_null($result["name"])){
    echo "No tiene valor";
}else{
    echo "Tiene valor";
```

Por que por ejemplo estas usando mal las comillas pues las usas para meter el número de tu WHERE pero luego no cierras las comillas del inicio

Como solo vas a devolver una columna en tu query te conviene usar `mysqli_fetch_row()`

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de mucha ayuda ‍♂️

Comment: @RaúlArcos recuerda calificar la respuesta que te ayudó así como aceptar la que te haya sido útil